# Probability game problem

Tags: probability, dice

I hope you could help me with this problem...

The game goes this way:

There are 6 players, numbered 1 to 6.

Player 1 starts the game, he rolls a die with six faces. If the result (x) of rolling the die is 1 then Player 1 wins. Else the player number x starts his turn. The game goes on and the Player x rolls the die, if the result (y) is equal to x then Player x win, else it's the turn of Player y. And so on.

What is the probability of the Player 1 to win?

I do this:
pn = probability that player 1 wins on the n round.
$$p_1 = 1/6$$
$$p_2 = 0$$
$$p_3 = \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}$$
$$p_4 = \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{4}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}$$

If I have a general formula for $p_n$ I would sum it for all value of $n$ and I have the probability I want. But I can't find this $p_n$.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability first player (ultimately) wins. Note that by symmetry all other players have equal probability of winning, so probability $(1-p)/5$. If first player tosses a $1$, she wins. If she tosses anything else, she becomes "another player." So $p=1/5+(5/6)((1-p)/5)$. This question has been asked a few times recently, so you may be able to find a more complete answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks!! And another question.. If player one has won, which is the expected number of times he has thrown the dice?

Comment: That's an interesting question which I do not recall being asked the couple of times I have seen this question in the last few days, but then I miss many questions. It is too bad to leave it buried in a comment to a question. You might want to ask the question separately, It would be good if you indicated what progress you have made, and in particular you know the probability that Player 1 wins.

Answer (score 0):

By conditioned on the first rolling, $P_{1wins}=1/6+(5/6)^5*P_{1 wins}$, then solve the equation.